# Nexus 7 ('13 CM11 Nightly) keeps waking up while charged

Tags: cyanogenmod, nexus-7

The tablet has been plugged into the wall and left alone. Every minute the screen turns on, and I have to press the power button to turn it off. This started last night as the tablet was quite warm from being turned on all last night.

What's the best way of detecting why it's turning on so often?

Looking at the running apps I don't see anything asking for permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, SuperSU you clever girl! Apparently Greenify was updated and it was constantly asking for root access. The prompt woke up the tablet each time. Boy do I feel silly now!